# Cloned repo not opening in local server

Tags: git, next.js, git-clone, repo

I  cloned this [repo](https://github.com/mariesta/nextjs-shopify-ecommerce)  to play around with it and ran **npm install** and **npm run dev**, which should be running it in the local server. but I got an error. and I have no idea what its going on about. since even the how to use instructions only say npm install
npm run dev i even tried running the other scripts "build" and "start" but nothing changed. below is a screenshot of the terminal errors as well as the browser errors[image: browser error]

[image: terminal error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your `SHOPIFY_STORE_FRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN` and `SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN` it should work.

Remember to create a `.env`file and add the two credentials.

Comment: i created the env file and copied the SHOPIFY_STORE_FRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN= and SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN= but the are empty variables any idea how to generate that token, as well as the domain. or do you have a resource I can take a look at?

Comment: I think you can log in to [Shopify Dev](https://shopify.dev/). I'm sure once you log in you will be able to create your credentials there. Also read the docs of the library your repo is using here [Shopify-Buy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-buy) you'll get the idea.